# How to check if a number exists between two given positions in fastest way?

Tags: c++, search

I'm given a number say N and its corresponding positions in an Array. 
Say the positions (indices) given are:

```
4 5 8 11 13 15 21 28
```

I'm given two positions (indices) say x and y. Let x=7 and y=13.

I need to find how many occurrences of number is there between x and y (both included, y>=x). Like in above example the number exists at positions 8,11 and 13 which lies between positions x and y and thus answer is 3.

A simple approach would be the naive O(n) algorithm but I want to take advantage of fact that the poistions will always be given in ascending order. I think applying binary search in a modified manner can help but I'm facing  facing trouble.

```
// P is the array that stores positions(indices) of number
int start=0,End=n-1; // n is the size of array P
int mid=(start+End)/2;
int pos1=0,pos2=0;
while(End>start)
{
   mid=(start+End)/2;  
   if(P[mid]>=x && P[mid-1]<x && flag1!=0)
    {
        pos1=mid;
        flag1=0

    }
    if(P[mid]<=y && P[mid+1]>y && flag2!=0)
    {
        pos2=mid;
        flag2=0;
    }
    else if (P[mid]<x)
        start=mid;
    else
        End=mid;
 }
    int Number_Of_Occurence=(pos2-pos1);
```

Can you please suggest where my code may go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the advantage of STL library. `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` comes to mind.

Both have logarithmic complexity on sorted containers with random iterators.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <algorithm>  
#include <vector>     

int main() {

  std::vector<int> v = {4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 15, 21, 28};

  int low_value = 7;
  int high_value = 13;

  auto low = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), low_value);
  auto high = std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), high_value);

  std::cout << std::distance(low, high) << " elements in interval ["
            << low_value << ", " << high_value << "]" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm boldly assuming this isn't a homework problem... you need to find the indices of both endpoints however your code only has one "mid" variable. Assuming you reimplement the binary search for both endpoints correctly and you are worried about number of operations, you can re-order the conditional in the if statements so that they short-circuit on flag!=0 before checking two other conditions. ie:

```
if( !flag1 && P[mid1]>=x && P[mid1-1]<x ) {...}
```

is technically faster than

```
if( P[mid1]>=x && P[mid1-1]<x && !flag1 ) {...}
```

Next, division can be an expensive operation ... and you are dividing by 2. Use a bit shift instead:

```
jump_size = jump_size >> 2
```

Now throwing away the flag entirely, we might rewrite the code to look more like this:

```
// n is the size of array P
// start int the middle
int pos1=pos2=n>>2;
// jump size is how far we jump up or down looking for our index
int jump_size=pos1>>2;
while(jump_size)
{
   if(P[pos1]>x) { pos1 -= jump_size; }
   else if(P[pos1]<x) { pos1+=jump_size; }
   // similar for y and pos2
   jump_size=jump_size>>2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code :) It wasn't a homework problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use `floor(x)`-`ceil(y)` to find it in O(log N) time .
below is code for finding `ceil()`..

```
int ceilSearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int x)
{
  int i;    

  /* If x is smaller than or equal to first element,
    then return the first element */
  if(x <= arr[low])
    return low;  

  /* Otherwise, linearly search for ceil value */
  for(i = low; i < high; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] == x)
      return i;

    /* if x lies between arr[i] and arr[i+1] including
       arr[i+1], then return arr[i+1] */
    if(arr[i] < x && arr[i+1] >= x)
       return i+1;
  }         

  /* If we reach here then x is greater than the last element 
    of the array,  return -1 in this case */
  return -1;
}
```

You can easily modify it to make `floor()` function .

Another method is to use `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` as you are using `c++` .